# How can I set the number of hAxis text in google chart?

Tags: google-visualization

I am drawing the line chart which has date type hAxis.
drawing small chart which has many rows(data) make hAxis texts to '...'. I can not explicitly display hAxis text now. 
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*when there are many data* the text becomes slanted

reduce `chartArea.height` to provide enough room to display the labels

`chartArea.left` may need to be adjusted as well, to fully display the first label

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {id: 'Date', type: 'date'},
        {id: 'A', type: 'number'},
        {id: 'B', type: 'number'},
        {id: 'C', type: 'number'},
        {id: 'D', type: 'number'}
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 0, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 1, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 24}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 2, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 20}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 3, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 48}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 4, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 53}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 5, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 61}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 6, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 63}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 7, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 66}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 8, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 70}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 9, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 75}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 10, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 78}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2016, 11, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 80}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2017, 0, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 85}]},
        {c:[{v: new Date(2017, 1, 1)}, {v: 25}, {v: 50}, {v: 25}, {v: 90}]}
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      chartArea: {
        left: 52,
        height: '50%'
      },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MMM dd, yyyy'
      },
      height: 200,
      legend: 'none',
      title: 'Example',
      width: 240
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```